# Why my web application (ReactJS) doesn't accept the cookies sent by backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies

I have a frontend web app made in ReactJS, and a backend made in HapiJS. Backend is running on http://localhost:3000 and frontend in http://localhost:1234.

I'm trying to implement authentication based on cookies. In my frontend, I'm doing the request for login (where I expect to get the cookies back) using Axios.

In my backend, I already have the code that set the cookies like this (I was setting a second cookie just for testing purposes):

```
//Config for user session cookie
server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {

    cookie: {
        name: 'sid-example',
        isSameSite: 'None',
        path: '/',
        password: 'password-should-be-32-characters',
        isSecure: false,
        isHttpOnly: false
    },
    ...
}

//Config for a normal cookie
server.state('data', {
    ttl: null,
    isSecure: false,
    isHttpOnly: false,
    encoding: 'base64json',
    clearInvalid: true,
    strictHeader: true,
    isSameSite: 'None',
    path: '/'
});

//In my route's code where authentication takes place
//Set user session cookie
request.cookieAuth.set({ uuid });
//Set normal cookie
h.state('data', { foo: 'bar' });
```

When I do the request (login attempt), I can see in Chrome dev tools -> Network tab that the cookies are set and come as part of the response. In development, I'm not setting the cookies as httpOnly true nor secure, and this can be seen in the request details.

[image: cookies come as part of the response]

However, when I check the application cookies, I cannot see them. In the application tab in dev tools, I can see noo cookies (I already refreshed the tab).

[image: no cookies set for the application - 1]

It detects there are 2 cookies but they are not shown:

[image: cookies count show they are there, but not set]
[image: no cookies shown]

Also, if I attempt to make requests using Axios, expecting the cookie to be sent back to the server (to authorize the request), they are not sent (I'm using the flag withCredentials in Axios (as explained [HERE](https://flaviocopes.com/axios-credentials/)). This can be seen in the Network tab as well (in the column cookies shows the count of cookies sent, while in Set Cookies the ones that are set either by the server or from the web app).

[image: cookies not sent]

Also I already disabled (for testing purposes) the browser flags #same-site-by-default-cookies and #cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure, as I'm not running it via HTTPS. Is there anything I'm missing that is preventing the browser to accept these cookies?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to use this setting in the backend:

- SameSite = 'None'
- Secure = True

(for localhost, Secure=True works, I guess)

On the client side, apart from including `withCredentials: true` in the subsequent requests, I had to include that in **the initial login request** as well, otherwise the browser doesn't consider the `set-cookie` headers in the response.